# Does INADDR_ANY interfaces include VMware Network Adapter?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, vmware, iptables

My code is currently making use of INADDR_ANY, I am testing to see if I am able to send packets from a VM client through a Ubuntu router, [using IPTables] to my host machine.

I am able to ping the Host machine from the client behind the Linux router and the client from the host machine, but when I send a UDP packet it never arrives at the host machine.

The problem is either in one of these two places, the IPTables I set up for routing are not working properly, or in my server code where I am binding to INADDR_ANY, INADDR_ANY does not include VMware Interfaces.

I have looked around, but I could not find specific information. From what I understand there is not reason why it should not work.

**Extending Question:**

According to [this](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/TOP/NAT+Traversal+Testing) If I run the commands I would be able to replicated the respective NAT, but were it says ***public ip goes here*** and ***private ip goes here*** is it referring to the destination IP or the public and private interface IP; i.e the IP addresses of eth0 and eth1 ?

***Solved***

I was setting the iptable rules on the wrong eth card ! So make sure that you are applying the commands on the correct eth.

Comment: I used a windows XP machine with VM with ubuntu linux.  The project involved two way communication over the internet, utilizing beth UDP and TCP protocols.  the Linux ran an apache2 web server, a web server application, and a client application.  Using the 127.0.0.1 loopback IP, I had no problems performing testing.  Changing the IP to the real/remote server gave no problems.  I used 'INADDR_ANY' (which is actually a poor choice when regarding security issues) and it all worked very well.

Comment: could you post the socket setup code for the client and server apps.  In my answer, I have posted how I did it.

Comment: INADDR_ANY is meant to bind to a port on **all** IP interfaces.  The problem is likely in your firewall setup.  Do you allow the firewall to dynamically open ports that are "outbound" from "behind" the firewall?  Have you tried disabling the firewall on the router (and on the machines) to see if that works?

Comment: The machine behind the firewall is a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, and I have turned off the firewall for the time being. For the router setup I have ran the following commands: 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination <private ip goes here>

That should create a full cone NAT and allow UDP packets through

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall on your host machine?

Comment: Yes, all firewalls are off, still nothing, do you perhaps know of a way I can simulate different cone NATs another way other than IPTables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is the client side of a UDP connection.

This worked with ubuntu linux, over VM, over windows XP.

Note: code statements on the left margin are (generally) for debug

Note: system functions 'sendto()' and 'recvfrom()' are the correct calls for UDP communications.

Note: the function capitalization, etc  are per the local the coding style being used.

Note: as with any 'real life' project, the majority of the code is to handle errors.

You will probably be most interested in the `create_UDP_socket()` function.

```
/* *************** Included files************************************* */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    // for system() and itoa() utilities
#include <stdarg.h>    // for va_list(), etc
#include <string.h>    // string handling utilities
#include <semaphore.h> // semaphores handling utilities

#include <fcntl.h>     // symbolic definitions for flags bits
#include <sys/types.h> // contains definitions of data types used in system calls
#include <sys/socket.h>// type definitions (I.E. struct sockaddr_in)
#include <sys/stat.h>  // symbolic definitions for permission bits and open()
#include <sys/ipc.h>   // ipc interface utilities

#include <sys/shm.h>   // shared memory utilities
#include <arpa/inet.h> // defines INADDR_ANY, etc

#include <errno.h>     // for accessing errno and related functions
#include <stdbool.h>   // define true, false, bool
#include <time.h>

    // contains common data type definitions
#include "localTypes.h"

    // contains data definitions for ON and OFF, enum enumReturnStatus
#include "Defines.h"

    // contains prototypes for writing to Log file
#include "CommonWriteLog.h"

    // contains prototypes, and data type definitions
#include "CommonConfiguration.h"

    //contains prototypes for globally visible functions in this file
#include "Common_UDP_Utilities.h"


/* *************** Global variables *********************************** */



/* *************** File Static Variables ****************************** */



/* *************** Code *********************************************** */



enum enumReturnStatus create_UDP_socket( INT32 taskSelector, INT32 *pUDPsocket_FD )
{
    enum enumReturnStatus returnStatus = eRS_Success; // indicate success
    INT32 LocalPort;
    INT32 socket_FD;
    struct sockaddr_in *pLocal_sockaddr;

char *txtAddress;

    if( is_taskSelector_Valid( taskSelector ) )
    { // then parameters valid

        socket_FD = get_UDPsocket_FD( eTask_Retrieve_GPS );

        if( 0 >= socket_FD )
        { // then socket not yet opened

            pLocal_sockaddr = get_pUDPsocket_sockaddr( taskSelector );

txtAddress = inet_ntoa((*pLocal_sockaddr).sin_addr);
fprintf(stdout, "OPENING SOCKET on socket addresss: %s \n", txtAddress );       

            if( NULL != pLocal_sockaddr )
            { // then, sockaddr configured

                LocalPort = get_UDPsocket_LocalPort( taskSelector );

fprintf(stdout, "OPENING SOCKET on PORT: %d \n", LocalPort );       

                if( 0 <= LocalPort )
                { // then port configured

                    socket_FD = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );

                    if( -1 != socket_FD )
                    { // then, socket creation successful

                        int TurnOn = 1;

                        returnStatus = setsockopt( socket_FD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &TurnOn, sizeof( TurnOn ) );

                        if ( eRS_Success == returnStatus )
                        { // then setsockopt() successful

                            bzero((char *) pLocal_sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) );
                            pLocal_sockaddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
                            pLocal_sockaddr->sin_port = htons( LocalPort );
                            pLocal_sockaddr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // todo: change to specific GPS IP address

                            CommonWriteLog( eLL_Info, 
                                "INFO:File:%s: Line:%d:\n\t%s 0X%08X %d\n\n",
                                __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                                "addr.sin_port =",
                                pLocal_sockaddr->sin_port,
                                pLocal_sockaddr->sin_port );

                            returnStatus = bind( socket_FD, (struct sockaddr *)pLocal_sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr) );

                            if( eRS_Success == returnStatus )
                            { // then bind successful

                                returnStatus = set_UDPsocket_FD( taskSelector, socket_FD );

                                if( eRS_Success != returnStatus )
                                { // then set_UDPsocket_FD failed

                                    CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                                        get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_string ),
                                        __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                                        "Function:set_UDPsocket_FD() failed" );

                                    returnStatus = eRS_UDP_Create_Failure; // indicate error occurred

                                    close( socket_FD );
                                    socket_FD = -1;
                                }

                                // set callers data
                                *pUDPsocket_FD = socket_FD;
                            }

                            else
                            { // else, bind() failed

                                CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                                    get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_taskSelector_dataIndex_string_string ),
                                    __FILE__, __LINE__,
                                    taskSelector, 0, 
                                    "LibFunc:bind() failed",
                                    strerror(errno) );
                            } // endif( bind )
                        }

                        else
                        { // else setsockopt() failed

                            CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                                get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_taskSelector_dataIndex_string_string ),
                                __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                                taskSelector, 0,
                                "LibFunc:setsockopt( SO_REUSEADDR ) failed",
                                strerror(errno) );

                        } // endif( SO_REUSEADDR )
                    }

                    else
                    { // else failed to create socket

fprintf(stdout, "FAILED TO OPEN SOCKET: \n" );       
fflush(stdout);
system("sync;sync;");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


                        CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                            get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_taskSelector_dataIndex_string_string ),
                            __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                            taskSelector, 0,
                            "LibFunc:socket() failed",
                            strerror(errno) );

                        returnStatus = eRS_SystemCall_Failure; // indicate error occured
                    } // endif( socket )
                }

                else
                { // else port not configured

                    CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                        get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_taskSelector_dataIndex_string ),
                        __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                        taskSelector, 0,
                        "port not configured" );

                    returnStatus = eRS_Configuration_Failure;  // indicate error occurred
                }
            } 

            else
            { // else get pUDP sockaddr failed

                CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                    get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_taskSelector_dataIndex_string ),
                    __FILE__, __LINE__,
                    taskSelector, 0, 
                    "Function:get_pUDPsocket_sockaddr() failed" );

                returnStatus = eRS_UDP_Create_Failure;  // indicate error occurred
            } // endif( get_pUDPsocket_sockaddr() successful )
        } // endif( socket already open )
    }

    else
    { // else, bad parameters

        returnStatus = eRS_UDP_Create_Failure;

        CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
            get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_digit_string ),
            __FILE__, __LINE__, 
            taskSelector,
            "Parameter:taskSelector out of range" );
    }

    return( returnStatus );
} // end create_UDP_socket()



enum enumReturnStatus write_UDP_socket( INT32 Socket_FD, char *pSocket_OutBuffer, INT32 Size, struct sockaddr *pTo_sockaddr, INT32 *pWriteCount )
{
    enum enumReturnStatus returnStatus = eRS_Success; // indicate success
    INT32 flags = 0;
    INT32 sendtoStatus;



    // do not call CommonWriteLog() to help avoid extranious 'recursion' messages in logs
    // and to avoid recrusive operation

    sendtoStatus = 
    sendto( Socket_FD, pSocket_OutBuffer, Size, flags,pTo_sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr) );

    if( 0 <= sendtoStatus )
    { // then, sendto() successful

        *pWriteCount = sendtoStatus;

        if( sendtoStatus != Size )
        { // then not all char sent
            CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
                "ERROR:File:%s: Line:%d:\n\t%s:num2Send:%d, numSent:%d\n\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__, 
                "LibFunc:sendto() failed",
                 Size, sendtoStatus );

            returnStatus = eRS_UDP_Write_Failure;  // indicate error occurred
        }
    }

    else
    {
        CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
            get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_string_string ),
            __FILE__, __LINE__, 
            "LibFunc:sendto() failed",
            strerror(errno) );

        returnStatus = eRS_SystemCall_Failure; // indicate error occurred
        *pWriteCount = 0;
    }

    return( returnStatus );
} // end write_UDP_socket()



enum enumReturnStatus read_UDP_socket( INT32 Socket_FD, char *pSocket_InBuffer, INT32 Size, INT32 *pReadCount )
{
    enum enumReturnStatus returnStatus = eRS_Success; 
    INT32   readStatus  = 0; // result of call to recvfrom()
    INT32   flags       = 0; // option parameter for call to recvfrom()
    struct  sockaddr_in from_sockaddr;
    UINT32  slen        = 0; // sizeof struct sockaddr_in



    memset( &from_sockaddr, 0x00, sizeof(from_sockaddr) );
    slen = sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );
    readStatus = recvfrom( Socket_FD, pSocket_InBuffer,Size, flags,(struct sockaddr*)&from_sockaddr, &slen );          // filled during call


    if( 0 > readStatus )
    { // then, an I/O error occurred
        CommonWriteLog( eLL_Error, 
            get_pFormatString( eFormat_EFFL_string_string ),
            __FILE__, __LINE__, 
            "LibFunc:recvfrom() failed",
            strerror(errno) );

        *pReadCount = 0;
        returnStatus = eRS_SystemCall_Failure; // indicate error occurred
    }

    else
    { //else 0 or more bytes read

        // update callers' info
        *pReadCount = readStatus;
    }

    return( returnStatus );
} // end read_UDP_socket()



/* ******************************************************************** **
** End of source file: Common_UDP_Utilities.c
** ******************************************************************** */
```

Comment: Thank you for providing code, but I already have code that works on public server. From what you said I can than conclude that INADDR_ANY does work with VMware interfaces. Must be something wrong in the Linux IPTables. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.